# NODE JS: Not able to delete data from Firebase Realtime Database when looping thru allData

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete specific data from Firebase running thru a forEach loop, but only the first item is removed. All the rest is skipped. I can't figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the entire file I am using split into sections here:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var moment = require('moment');    
var serviceAccount = require("path-to-json.json");    
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "app.firebaseio.com"
});    
var db = admin.database();
```

function call to remove data by getting all data first

```
function removeOldData() {
    var ref = db.ref('/App/Items/');   
    var itemValue;

    ref.on("value",
        function (snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(element => {
                itemValue = element.val();
                if(itemValue.date === 'Invalid date' || itemValue.date === '') {
                    deleteData(element.key);
                }else {
                    date = moment(itemValue.date, "MMMM DD, YYYY").format()
                    if(moment().diff(date, 'days') > 14){
                        deleteData(element.key);
                    }
                }           
            });
        },
        function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        }
   );
}
```

Delete item function

```
function deleteData(key) {
    console.log("Deleting ... " + key);

    var ref = db.ref('/App/Items/' + key + '/');
    ref.remove();
}
```

Exports

```
module.exports = { removeOldData };
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more tries and research, using `ref.once` fixed the issue for me.